# Google Maps Javascript API v3, Jquery Tabs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have tried everything possible.. unminified all javascript, still can't get the map to load properly inside the tab.

Trying to use this custom code too with no success

```
jQuery('.tabs-shortcode > ul').bind('tabsshow', function(e, ui) {
           if (ui && ui.panel) {
                          jQuery('.mapp-canvas', ui.panel).each(function() {
                                         var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                                         if (id) {
                                                        window[id].resize();
                                         }
                          });
           }
```

});

webpage:  http://bit.ly/UTHskS

thanks in advance,
Andy

Comment: Here is another solution that doesn't work unfortunately but might provide some insights.. That won't help because the problem isn't with maps or the plugin.  The problem is that the tabs control isn't triggering the tabsshow event.  

Let's try this instead, it should (hopefully) correct the tab control and fix both problems:
1) Remove the custom code I gave you below
2) In your custom.js file change this:
       jQuery('.tabs-shortcode > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 150 } });
To
       jQuery('.tabs-shortcode').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 150 } });

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to trigger the Resize event to the map when the tab opens.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Comment: thank you so much but i am not sure how to apply this for my specific case. If you could be a bit more detailed on the actual code change I would be most grateful. Andy

Comment: Oh, you are using a word press plugin for map. Well, I'm reading the document....

Comment: actually now i am using an iframe if you can look at the revised code.. the problem now is that the map is not being centered to the placemarker...

Comment: Click the marker; then open the infowindow before generating the embed code. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try though, this code would solve the problem.
Please try this code.

```
jQuery('.tabs-shortcode > ul').bind('tabsshow', function(e, ui) {
  if (ui && ui.panel) {
    jQuery('.mapp-canvas', ui.panel).each(function() {
      var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      if (id) {
        window[id].resize();
      }
      setTimeout(function(){
        if (mapp0) {
          google.maps.event.trigger(mapp0.getMap(), "resize");
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, I did try this but still the same problem unfortunately :(